# Rendering data quicker in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, performance

Is there a way to speed up rendering data into ArcMap ?

When I converted the raster to polygon and some data would render quicker and some other renders slow.

I am wondering if I could add the spatial index to the data that renders slow.

Would that work or is there anything that I could make the data render quicker?

Comment: By load do you mean draw or render?

Comment: Yeah, I meant render

Comment: changed title from Load to Render.

Comment: @PROBERT - maybe you could give us a hint at your gdb use/requirements. Any rdbms you might be considering. Network, user #s, field use, etc.

Comment: It's because you haven't accepted any answers. Go back to the questions you've asked and clicked the checkmark next to the answer that was most useful to you

Comment: Thanks. I am new here so been here like a month so far...very good information website !

Comment: Also, are you using ArcGIS 9.3 - if so take a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3280/9-2-to-9-3-1-desktop-how-to-troubleshoot-slow-data-access-with-shps/ (/shameless plug)

Comment: om-henners, Thanks. and by the way, yes we have ArcGIS 9.1.3 I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On top of Brads suggestions also look at putting data into an File Geodatabase and compacting the database if the data is static.

We compact our FGDBs and then just uncompact them when data updates are needed.

See Esri [help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Compacting_file_and_personal_geodatabases/003n0000007t000000/).

Answer (score 4):

It is all about throughput.

1. normalizing data. (using rdbms techniques) to make the data as light as possible.
2. spatial indexing
3. smart data type selection (i.e. fgdb for field ops, rdbms for enterprise, raster mosaics, tiling, Cache)
4. efficient network resources. (if the bottleneck is the file server even a small file is going to render slowly).
5. There are some documents available on [ESRI Resource Center](http://blogs.esri.com/dev/blogs/geodatabase/archive/2008/04/03/five-best-practices-for-maintaining-an-enterprise-geodatabase.aspx)
   and for [Caching](http://help.arcgis.com/en/communitybasemap/10.0/help/index.html#//01010000003s000000.htm)
   Also if you are a single machine (no network), no enterprise considerations, you should take a read here [Derek Law has some good advice on some whitepapers](http://forums.esri.com/thread.asp?c=158&f=2290&t=296103).

Comment: +RAM (8GB on Windows 7 is much faster than XP)

Answer (score 0):

i agree with Brad's ideas and one more thing is projection. The data loaded in ArcGIS should be the same of projection, it would render faster.